# RegEx for hashtag without #

Tags: regex

I have problem with creating regex for hashtag in my Rails app.
These words should not be valid:

```
'aa#', 'b#b', 'ccc#', '12#', '#33', "asd ef", "aa aa", "33 22", "#aad dd", "!!!# assd", "#aa dd", "dd a#a"
```

These words should be valid (the words with only one word and without #:

```
'super', 'extra', 'bomba', 'slit!!', 'd@@b', 'a13b', 'db3a', 'a3'
```

My current regex: `/#\s*/` - this work but without free spaces('asd ef' passed :-/ )

Comment: Do you really need a regex for this?  Why not simple string search for `#` or whitespace?

Comment: Can you provide your current regex

Comment: Why do you need a regex instead of using a simple string search?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Are you getting a list of strings and trying to filter out the ones that have # in them? Are you getting a string with many words and are trying to pick the ones without # in them?

Comment: Are "words" always wrapped in quotes?

Comment: Quotes is only for cleaner code.

Comment: then how can a "word" have a space in it? ie what does "the words with only one word" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[^\s#']+$
```

Add any other chars to the character class that are *not* "valid" word chars.

Comment: Now, my code: `validates :hashtag, format: { without: /[^\s#']+/ }` works, but word 'super' is invalid :/

Comment: @Kam I think you either want `with: /[^\s#']+/ ` (not `without:`), but that's just a guess - I am not familiar with that DSL

Comment: When I type it with with- word 'aa#' and 'asd ef' is valid. It should not be valid.

Comment: @Kam try adding `^` at the start and `$` at the end - see edit.

Comment: In ruby this - `/\A[^\s#']+\z/` work perfectly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested much but I would start with

```
(\w+(?!#)(?!\s+).)\w+
```